# How can I implement a token-based auth with passport.js and google auth in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, google-oauth, mern

I'm building a MERN stack web app and is trying to use passport.js for authentication.

The frontend in my app communicates with backend through the RESTful api and they are planed to be deployed in two different containers. I've looked up some most widely used passport google strategies as well as blog posts for implementation, and it seems like all of them are assuming the implementation of a server side render web app.

In my frontend, I'm using the React component [react-google-login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) to get the user profile from Google. But I'm unsure about what passport strategy is preferable, or applicable, for this use case of mine.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Use https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2.

Comment: the `passport-google-oauth2` is what I've been using but it doesn't provide a way where the auth operation is performed in the frontend instead of backend.

Comment: Yes the authentication is done in the frontend, i.e. the frontend will receive `access_token` and `id_token` from accounts.google.com after user authenticate the application, then the tokens are sent to the backend server. It would be perfect if `passport-google-oauth2` can support authentication through token instead of redirect user to Google auth server, but I haven't found a way to do that. Just wondering if there is another strategy that's suitable for the purpose.

Comment: Your component has ability to get the token and other values through onSuccess callback. There is a demo [here](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/tree/master/demo)